# angularjs mobile ui multiple modals not working

Tags: angularjs

I am implementing 3 different modals in the same view, 
but only the one that's placed last could be activated.. my code:

```
    <div ui-content-for="modals"> 
      <div class="modal" ui-if="blockPersonModal" ui-state='blockPersonModal'> 
            <div class="modal-backdrop in"></div> 
            <div class="modal-dialog"> 
              <div class="modal-content"> 
                    <div class="modal-header"> 
                      <button class="close" 
                                      ui-turn-off="blockPersonModal">&times;</button> 
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Block</h4> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="modal-body"> 
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio quo illum nihil voluptatem earum optio repellendus, molestias illo facere, ea non. Possimus assumenda illo accusamus voluptatibus, vel corporis maxime quam.</p> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="modal-footer"> 
                      <button ui-turn-off="blockPersonModal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button> 
                      <button ui-turn-off="blockPersonModal" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> 
                    </div> 
              </div> 
            </div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
    <div ui-content-for="modals"> 
      <div class="modal" ui-if="RequestIdentificationModal" ui-state='RequestIdentificationModal'> 
            <div class="modal-backdrop in"></div> 
            <div class="modal-dialog"> 
              <div class="modal-content"> 
                    <div class="modal-header"> 
                      <button class="close" 
                                      ui-turn-off="RequestIdentificationModal">&times;</button> 
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Request Identification</h4> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="modal-body"> 
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio quo illum nihil voluptatem earum optio repellendus, molestias illo facere, ea non. Possimus assumenda illo accusamus voluptatibus, vel corporis maxime quam.</p> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="modal-footer"> 
                      <button ui-turn-off="RequestIdentificationModal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button> 
                      <button ui-turn-off="RequestIdentificationModal" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> 
                    </div> 
              </div> 
            </div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
    <div ui-content-for="modals"> 
      <div class="modal" ui-if="ReportModal" ui-state='ReportModal'> 
            <div class="modal-backdrop in"></div> 
            <div class="modal-dialog"> 
              <div class="modal-content"> 
                    <div class="modal-header"> 
                      <button class="close" 
                                      ui-turn-off="ReportModal">&times;</button> 
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Report</h4> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="modal-body"> 
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio quo illum nihil voluptatem earum optio repellendus, molestias illo facere, ea non. Possimus assumenda illo accusamus voluptatibus, vel corporis maxime quam.</p> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="modal-footer"> 
                      <button ui-turn-off="ReportModal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button> 
                      <button ui-turn-off="ReportModal" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> 
                    </div> 
              </div> 
            </div> 
      </div> 
    </div>
```

if I am changing the order of the modals in my code, still only the last one will show up.

how can I define three different modals in the new angularjs mobile ui? 
unfourtanatley, the docs lacks clear information about how to do such a thing.

thanks,

Yonatan.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

The correct way to write multiple modals:

```
<div ui-content-for="modals">
       <div class="modal">....</div>
       <div class="modal">....</div>
       <div class="modal">....</div>
 </div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div ui-content-for="modals">
       <div class="modal">....</div>
</div>

<div ui-content-for="modals">
       <div class="modal">....</div>
</div>

<div ui-content-for="modals">
       <div class="modal">....</div>
</div>
```